# MySQL Update Values: How to separate 1 & -1 in query

Tags: mysql

I have this column on my database which contains either 1, -1 or 0. Now I want to change the values of all 1s to "YES", all 0s to "NO" and all -1s to "PROBED". I actually kind of know how to do it but the issue is MySQL did not properly recognize -1 and 1s so basically -1 and 1 were both changed to "YES" during my first try with a different query. Now I came up with a new one.

```
update test

SET AMEX = CASE WHEN AMEX = '1' THEN 'YES' END,
        AMEX CASE WHEN AMEX = '-1' THEN 'PROBED' END,
        AMEX = CASE WHEN AMEX = '0' THEN 'NO' END
```

I'm thinking of using this query but it might end up converting all 1s and -1s to YES and I dont want to risk it since I don't know all the -1 entries and the database is pretty big.

Comment: What is the type of the `AMEX` column?

Comment: @JPG Why did you delete that answer?

Comment: My AMEX is in varchar

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Haha, just for reading question one more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `AMEX` is indeed a `varchar` column, then your guess isn't far off, e.g. use:

```
UPDATE test
SET AMEX = CASE WHEN AMEX = '1'  THEN 'YES'
                WHEN AMEX = '0'  THEN 'NO'
                WHEN AMEX = '-1' THEN 'PROBED' END
WHERE AMEX IN ('1', '0', '-1')
```

I added a `WHERE` clause which will ensure that an `UPDATE` only takes place on a record which has an `AMEX` value of 1, 0, or -1, just in case you have other types of data in there.

Comment: Tried this but sadly, it converted all 1s and -1s to YES

Comment: Are you _certain_ that `AMEX` is varchar?  Are you _certain_ that your -1 values were really saved as -1, and not as 1 ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. But I think I've figured it out. I just noticed that my varchar limit is set to 4 and the word PROBED has 6 so that might be the issue

Comment: @AndyMarty Yes, this is a problem.  Increase the width of the column: `ALTER TABLE test MODIFY AMEX VARCHAR(55);`

Answer (score 1):

Simply fix the syntax error:

```
update test
SET AMEX = CASE WHEN AMEX = '1' THEN 'YES'
                WHEN AMEX = '-1' THEN 'PROBED'
                WHEN AMEX = '0' THEN 'NO' END;
```